# Proving residual/$\sigma \sim$ $N(0,1)$

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, normal-distribution, multivariate-regression

I would like to proof that
$$\frac{Y_i - \hat Y_i}{\sigma} \sim N(0,1)$$
holds where I refere to the general multivariate regression case, i.e. $Y_i = x_i \beta + \epsilon_i$ with $\epsilon_i \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$.

I know that if Y is normal distributed, $\frac{Y-E[Y]}\sigma \sim N(0,1)$ holds. Since $E[Y_i] = x_ib = \hat  Y_i$, the claim would trivially follow.

However, if I try to compute the variance of $\frac{Y_i - \hat Y_i}{\sigma}$ by hand, I don't obtain 1 and I don't know where I miss something. My approach is:

$$Var\left[\frac{Y_i - \hat Y_i}{\sigma}\right] = \sigma^{-2} Var[Y_i - \hat Y_i]$$ $$ = \sigma^{-2} Var[(I_n - H)_{ii}Y_i] = \sigma^{-2}(1-h_{ii})Var[Y_i] =\sigma^{-2+2}(1-h_{ii})=1-h_{ii} $$

where H denotes the hat matrix and I used that $(I_n-H)$ is also a projection matrix, hence idempotent and symmetric. So, for the claim, I would need that $1-h_{ii} = 1$ which is obviously not true...

Maybe someone could point out where a mistake happens? Thank you in advance for your help and clarification! :-)

Comment: The mistake is at the outset, because what you are trying to prove is false. The simplest case should help you understand: when there is a single observation $(x_1,Y_1)$ then $\hat Y_1=Y_1,$ whence $(Y_1-\hat Y_1)/\sigma=0$ is constant--obviously not a standard Normal variate.

Comment: Thank you very much that clarifies it and makes sense @whuber ! Before posting the question I was also wondering if the claim is really true. But could you may explain why the line "I know that if Y is normal distributed, $\frac{Y-E[Y]}\sigma \sim N(0,1)$ holds. Since $E[Y_i] = x_ib = \hat  Y_i$, the claim would trivially follow. " is false or where the mistake is hiding here?

Comment: One possible strategy for this type of problem is to use the fact that the expected value is 0 and then just work with the expected value of the residual squared rather than the variance.

Comment: By "$\hat Y_i$" one would generally understand (as I have here) the value of the OLS fit for observation $i.$  It is obtained by plugging in the *estimated* coefficients into the model along with the explanatory value $x_i.$  That is not the same thing as $E[Y],$ which is a (true, data-independent) property of the marginal distribution of $Y.$ The dependence on the estimated coefficients (as well as on $x_i$ itself!) is revealed to you by the appearance of the hat matrix diagonal elements $h_{ii}$ in your calculations.

Comment: Ohhh you are totally right! Thanks so much to both of you. I messed up that $E[Y] = x_i \beta$ holds and **not** that $E[Y] = x_i b$. Thank you!